# Unable to get master token - java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

what is that :

> Unable to get master token
>                                                                                       java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
>   act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms
>   (has extras) } without permission
>   com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
>                                                                                           at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1161)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:383)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzc(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.D(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                           at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>                                                                                           at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

my manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- [END gcm_permission] -->

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity">
        </activity>

        <!-- Firebase Notifications -->
        <service
            android:name="com.badboys.gcm.service.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name="com.badboys.gcm.service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- ./Firebase Notifications -->
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

> permission
>           android:name=".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
>           android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Set up a GCM Client for Android](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest) if you've missed anything.

From what I read, you're missing the 1st permission that prevents other applications from registering/receiving your messages.

```
"packagename"+".permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
```

You're also missing a few items that may cause the issue.

Now, if you want a [Firebase-specific implementation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest), change the intent filter action of the `MyFirebaseMessagingService` to

```
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
```

and `MyFirebaseInstanceService` to

```
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
```